# Strongly continuous Operator.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I can not understand the notion "strongly continuous operator on a Banach space". Is it the continuity with respect to norm on a Banach space?

Can someone kindly explain this to me along with reference?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) helpful?

Comment: Typically one speaks of a strongly continuous representation of a group - are you sure you mean a single operator here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it the continuity with respect to norm on a Banach space?*

As explained in the Kantorovitz's book ([Topics in Operator Semigroups](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bQdLAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Shmuel+Kantorovitz%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMImq7VhfmByQIVzIqQCh2knQAv#v=onepage&q&f=false)) through the pages 3-6, the answer is *yes*.

Here is a (adapted) citation:

> In the general situation, an operator semigroup is a function $T (\cdot) : [0,\infty) \to B(X)$ (where $B(X)$ denotes the Banach algebra of all bounded linear operators on the given Banach space $X$), such that
>
> - $T (s)T (t) = T (s + t)$ for $s,t ≥ 0$
>     (the *semigroup identity*) and
> - $T (0)$ is the identity operator $I$.
>
> The *continuity at* $0$ (or $C_0$) condition is
>   $$\lim_{t\to0^+}T (t)x = x$$
>   for all $x \in X$ (limit in $X$ **with respect to the norm**). This is right continuity at zero in the strong operator topology (s.o.t.) on $B(X)$; in brief, “strong continuity at $0$.”
>
> A $C_0$-*semigroup* (or *semigroup strongly right-continuous at zero*) is a semigroup of operators that satisfies the $C_0$-condition.

---

**ADDENDUM.** Maybe you find what you are looking for in the Engel's books ([One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear
Evolution Equations](https://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf) or [A Short Course on Operator Semigroups](https://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/2006/a-short-course-on-operator-semigroups/A_Short_Course_on_Operator_Semigroups.pdf)).

Here is an adapted citation (from the first one):

> ... ($T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is a *strongly continuous semigroup* if the
>   functional equation
>   $$\left\{\begin{align}
> &T(t + s) = T(t)T(s),\quad\text{ for all} \quad t, s \geq 0,\\
> &T(0) = I
> \end{align}\right.\tag{FE}$$
>   holds and the *orbit maps*
>   $$\xi_x:t\mapsto\xi_x(t):=T(t)x\tag{SC}$$
>   are continuous from $\mathbb{R}_+$ into $X$ for every $x\in X$.
>
> The property $(\text{SC})$ can also be expressed by saying that the map 
>   $$t\mapsto T(t)$$
>   is continuous from $\mathbb{R}_+$ into the space $B(X)$ of all bounded operators on $X$ endowed with the strong operator topology...
>
> These strongly continuous semigroups are the main objects in this book, and we are going to show how rich a theory and how many applications arise from the interplay of the functional equation $(\text{FE})$ and the requirement of strong continuity $(\text{SC})$...

Comment: I wasn't talking about $C_0$-semigroups. I asked about the elaboration of this notion for an individual operator $T(t)\in \{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$.

Comment: @ShinningStar If you had said this in response to Hoseyn Heydari and Prahlad Vaidyanathan, I would not have posted this. Anyway, in the context of semigroups of operator, for each $t\geq 0$, $T(t):X\to X$ is a continuous linear operator. The concept of strongly continuity doesn't concerns to the individual mappings $x\mapsto T(t)x$; the strongly continuity concerns to the mapping $t\mapsto T(t)$. That is to say, the strongly continuity is defined with respect to $t$ (at least, usually). Could you give some details? Have you a reference or a specific context?

Comment: No I don't have any reference at the moment but thank you so much for your effort. If you can suggest me some reference for the detail study of strong continuity, It would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @ShinningStar I'm not sure what you need. However, to study strong continuity in the context of semigroups of operators, I would suggest the Engel's books (see the edit in my post).

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)